# Cannot convert value of type '[String : Double]' to expected argument type '[(String, Double)]' Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

What is wrong with this error? Are they not the same type? Someone please help I have been searching for hours and could not find anything. This error occurs when I try to put my [String : Double] into a parameter that requires a [(String : Double)] whats the difference? Thank you for your time

Comment: [String : Double] is a dictionary, [(String: Double)] is an array of tuple.

Comment: Post the function that takes that parameter. `func monkey(param: [(String : Double)]) { }` in playground gives `error: cannot create a single-element tuple with an element label`

Comment: No, these two are not the same type: `[String:Double]` is a dictionary from `String` to `Double`, while `[(String,Double)]` is an array of two-element tuples that pair up a `String` and a `Double`.

Answer (score 3):

`[String : Double]` is a dictionary. A dictionary consists of key and its corresponding value.

```
let dictionary = ["Age" : 20]
```

On the other hand,  `[(String : Double)]` is an array of tuple, actually they are in the space of dictionary and structure. They hold special kind of value, tuples are needed if we want to return multiple values from a function call.

```
let user = (name: "Ankur Lahiry", age: 25)
```

if any function return user then we can return two values from the function. We can extract the results like

```
let name = user.name
let age = user.age
```

I think you want to use array of dictionaries, `[[dictionary: Double]]`

Answer (score -2):

Looks like your function is accepting array of tuple of type **(String, Double)**. But you are trying to pass array of dictionaries of type **String: Double**.
Check if you need array of Tuple or Dictionary.

Comment: it's not technically a (String, Double). It's a (String: Double)

Comment: What do you mean by it? First declaration is tuple and second is dictionary. Right?